# What do the warnings written upon SARIMAX summary mean? Does it heavily affect my forecasting performance? and How to resolve it?

Tags: data-science, statsmodels, arima

These are the warnings. I can provide additional info of the SARIMAX summary should it be needed.

Warnings:

- Covariance matrix calculated using the outer product of gradients (complex-step).
- Covariance matrix is singular or near-singular, with condition number 3.39e+17. Standard errors may be unstable.

Answer (score 2):

The first one is actually more like a "note" than a "warning". It's just letting you know how the covariance matrix was computed.

The second one is letting you know that parameter estimates may be unstable. Sometimes this is an indication of overfitting, but it can also arise from other things. This may indicate that you should try a simpler model (which then might forecast better), but it does not mean that you have to do that.

Comment: Do you have any suggestions on how to fix over-fitting the model? I've worked on over-fitted image recognition models before, but am pretty new in optimizing time-series models.